# Can't declare a pure virtual function using a typedef with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why can't I use function typedefs to declare pure virtual functions with MSVC? This works with GCC.

In this code snippet, there is a linking error for `function`, but not `function2` ([Minimum working example in codepad with gcc](http://ideone.com/dw0r1H)), ([Minimum working example in Coliru with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/273322175d57bd06)).

edit: The exact linking error is:
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl cv::of2::Base::function(int)" (?function@Base@of2@cv@@UEAAHH@Z)`

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:

    typedef int func_t (int x);

    virtual func_t function = 0;

    virtual int function2(int x) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    func_t function;
    int function2 (int x);
};

int Derived::function(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int Derived::function2(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    Base * theClass = new Derived();

    std::cout << theClass->function(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << theClass->function2(2) << std::endl;

    delete theClass;

    return 0;
}
```

This is useful if I want to force multiple functions to have the same signature, so I can assign them to a function pointer.

Comment: Kinda hard to imagine what virtual data looks like.  Okay, I give up.

Comment: I don't see anything in C++11 that'd stop this working

Comment: @HansPassant Where do you see virtual data? The type of `function` is a function.

Comment: Do you mean that function2 links, but function1 doesn't? (Not what you have written!)

Comment: You say you get a linker error. Testing it online, I'm unable to get to the linking stage: I get a compiler error instead, a syntax error to be precise.

Comment: Have you tried mixing the typedef and non-typedef syntax between declaration and definition (both ways round)? In other words, is it the definition or the declaration that won't work with typedef, or the combination of the two?

Comment: @davidc Function typedefs can only be used for declaration, not definition. I swapped the derived class declarations around, and it was still `function` that didn't link, so it's the pure virtual declaration in the `Base` class that isn't happy.

Comment: @hvd What's the compilation error? Compiles for me with Visual Studio 2012, and breaks at linking (see edit).

Comment: @kmac "main.cpp(9): error C2258: illegal pure syntax, must be '= 0'", with the online compiler on rise4fun.com.

Comment: @hvd Hmm, that version of the compiler seems confused, it IS '= 0'. This seems to be an error for "in-place initialization of static const integral member data", which is not the case here. I'm sceptical of that online msvc compiler ;).

Comment: @davidc I swapped the declarations in `Derived`, and left them as-is in `Base` (where the problem is). The definitions are identical, so they're not causing the problem.

Comment: I think the typedef in a pure declaration may fail, as in a definition. It is a kind of definition that there is no definition :) (Speculation, I have no source of authority on that.)

Comment: @davidc Except that it's a linking error, not a compilation error. Which means it's looking for a definition?! Also, works in both gcc and clang.

Comment: Maybe need to refer to MS as to why their linker can't handle something that others can. :)

Comment: @davidc Yep, that seems to be the conclusion. I was hoping there would be a workaround.

Comment: Thinking about it, the online compiler (which is more up-to-date) probably detects `= 0` as an error if it's applied to something that cannot be pure (even if its detection is wrong), whereas the older compiler didn't detect it, silently discarded the `= 0`, and consequently required a definition for the member function it didn't realse was pure. As for a work-around, I'm trying to understand why you need one. If you don't use a typedef, functions with the same signatures still have the same type.

Comment: The typedef is useful to force the signatures of several methods to be the same, so I can assign them to function pointers. It's also cleaner. But yes, functionally I can get what i want by not using a typedef.

Comment: You might force them to have the same signature by redeclaring typedefs: `struct S { void a(); void b(); void c(); }; typedef decltype(&S::a) check_same_type; typedef decltype(&S::b) check_same_type; typedef decltype(&S::c) check_same_type;` (Note that this approach does not let the typedef be declared in-class.) You might also use static assertions with `std::is_same` for a similar effect, but it would be slightly more difficult to write, IMO.